# esri new Portal(myUrl) returns a dojo error: CancelError "All requests canceled"

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

Esri ArcGis Javascript API 3.18

I'm issuing a new Portal("myUrl") command and getting back an error.

It's a dojo error, "CancelError" "All requests canceled."

It's a new https installation of the api on a new federated portal.

I have code that works when calling the esri portal so I think my code is probably correct.   That would leave a installation configuration problem.
So far, I'm stumped.

My test web site is on the same webserver as the portal.

Here's a link to the plunkr with working code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/RFlStZbHA5axAD3J2KQt?p=preview

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>New Portal</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='mainContent'>
      <input id='message' value='initial value' />
    </div>

    <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
    <script>
    dojo.require('esri.arcgis.Portal');
    dojo.require("esri.IdentityManager");
    dojo.require("dojox.lang.aspect");

    var portalUrl = 'https://www.arcgis.com';
    var portal = null;
    var message = document.getElementById('message');

    var init = function() {
      message.setAttribute('value', 'pre new portal');
      portal = new esri.arcgis.Portal(portalUrl);
      message.setAttribute('value', 'past new portal');
      portal.on("error", function(errorMsg) {
         message.setAttribute('value', 'error=' | errorMsg.message);        
      });
      portal.on("load", function (data) {
         message.setAttribute('value', 'success');        
      });
    };

    message.setAttribute('value', 'pre init');
    dojo.ready(init);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, some progress.  This was helpful in getting the api configured correctly so I could create a new Map object and load it.

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011974
I knew about modifying the javascript files in the api, but not the portal settings.

Still cannot create a Portal object.

Comment: Here's an additional symptom:

If I want to access the portal as a human user, I navigate in my browser to:

    https://www.myurl.com/arcgis/home

when i create a new Portal object in javascript, I use either:
    https://www.myurl.com   or https://www.myurl.com/arcgis/home
I see the esri code issues a get request for:
    https://www.myurl.com/sharing/rest/portals/self

Anyone have any idea where the "sharing/rest/portals/self" is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the portal settings per this document made the api work for maps.

All the examples online show using this:

```
var portal = new Portal('www.myurl.com');
```

I found that using this worked:

```
var portal = new Portal('www.myurl.com/arcgis');
```

Basically, since some of this may be due to configuration settings I haven't seen, I would recommend determining what url gets called by the Portal object's internal code, and then trying increasingly long fragments of the initial url until you get success.